# There is a Number 1 Appearing on my HTML Page, even though I didn't put it there

Tags: php, css, html

I am designing a website and I have ran into a problem with my HTML. I am executing and echoing content from a PHP file to then display on my page, but my browser is adding a number 1 after the content from the PHP file has been parsed.

Here is my HTML (and PHP):

```
<section id="header">
<div style="float: left; padding-top: 0px; vertical-align: central;">
<a href="/home"><img src="/img/site/logo.png" alt="DibDibCraft Logo" height="50" width="167" class="logo" /></a>
</div>

<?php echo(include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php')); ?>
</section>
```

and here is the content from `header.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/layout.css" />

<div id="navBarBtnContainer">Hello</div>
```

The 1 is being placed after the content from `header.php` is parsed and befoe the end of the section (before the `</section>` mark). Here is a screenshot:

[image: Number 2 added to HTML page.]

As you can see, the number 1 is being added before `</section>`.

I have checked my code in a HTML and a PHP parser and both have returned no errors that would give a result like this.

I also don't know what the name of this error is (if it is an error), so I haven't been able to find help without asking on this site, so ny apologies if this is a duplicate question, could you please direct me to a question that may help with this problem if this is a duplicate.

Thanks a lot, DibDibs

PS: Could you also tell me why this is happening, this will help me avoid making the same error again in the future, thanks :)

Comment: `include` returns true/false (or any `return` value set in the included file) to signify success/failure of the include operation, which you're echoing out.

Comment: Yes, it is, sorry, but you don't have to downvote :(

Comment: No worries; I can see how it would have been difficult to find the duplicate question without knowing this was caused by include. I haven't downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for understanding :) and it must have been someone else then, or the guy that upvoted removed it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

problem with

```
<?php echo(include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php')); ?>
```

remove echo in this line

finally output is:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this, thank you :D
It's because I'm echoing the same thing twice isn't it!

Comment: Thanks, your a lifesaver, it worked :D

Comment: I will, won't let me do it for another 10 mins though ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php')
```

returns `Boolean` as `true == 1`
when you echo the previous line of code it returns 1 because it succeed and returned `true`

delete the `echo` and it will disappear

Comment: Makes sense, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of this code.

```
<?php echo(include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php')); ?>
```

You are actually `echo`ing the returned result of the nested `include()` statement call, which is `1` (loose `true` - don't ask me why PHP doesn't use boolean `true` here).

That would logically be the same as:

```
// this line generates expect HTML output
$success = include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/htm/header.php');
// this line generates unexpected 1 output
echo($success);
```

Since your include actually generates HTML output, your expected HTML is correctly rendered.  You then echo the `1` result of the include action, which causes `1` to be displayed.